# How to update the version of a parent/aggregator pom without updating the child modules?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, multi-module

Suppose I have a multi-module maven project, with a parent pom:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>

  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <!-- etc. -->
  </modules>
</project>
```

and several modules like:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
  </parent>
</project>
```

Now I am trying to update the version of the parent pom using the versions maven plugin, *without* updating the corresponding parent section in the child modules. That is, I want the parent to get a version of e.g. `0.2.0-SNAPSHOT`, while the child modules still refer to the `0.1.0` parent version in this example, i.e.:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
  </parent>
</project>
```

How can I do this?

I have tried just about every optional parameter for the `mvn versions:set` command that seemed like it could affect this behavior, including the maven `-N` flag, in various combinations, but none of them worked.
Is it possible to do this with the versions maven plugin? Is there some other way?

It seems like I am having the opposite problem as described in these questions:

[Versions plugin not updating child modules, just parent being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475220/versions-plugin-not-updating-child-modules-just-parent-being-updated)

[versions-maven-plugin on mutli module project with aggregator pom does not set versions on modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761282/versions-maven-plugin-on-mutli-module-project-with-aggregator-pom-does-not-set-v)

Note that I am trying to automate this task, which is why I would to run some plugin/command to achieve the desired result (manually you can obviously just edit the relevant line in the parent pom).

Comment: Is the `<modules>` block in the parent POM, or in a separate POM?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  That said the simplest way is most likely just modifying the XML with an XSLT processor.

Comment: The `<modules>` block is in the parent POM.
I would like to be able to maintain a single main branch, while being able to update modules independently.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use branching in your version control system (e.g. git).

Let's assume you work on branch `develop` with the 0.1.0 version.

1. merge your `develop` branch to `master`. The master branch is now 0.1.0
2. check out your `develop` branch again.
3. upgrade the project on develop branch to 0.2.0-SNAPSHOT
4. if you need to point to the 0.1.0 version of any artifact, you can do that now.

Now, your master branch has 0.1.0, and the 0.1.0 artifacts exist in your local maven repository.

The develop branch has version 0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not really what I'm looking for. I understand I can use multiple branches, but I would rather not because I'm trying to run it in an automated pipeline and it creates the possibility for a conflict that has to be manually resolved. Especially because the different modules may get updated simultaneously, but independently.